ModuleNotFound error in migration of new model
This is my model:
class Company(models.Model):
    class LTRCharField(models.CharField):
        def formfield(self, **kwargs):
            defaults = {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'dir': 'ltr'})}
            defaults.update(kwargs)
            return super().formfield(**defaults)

    title = models.CharField(_('company title'), max_length=255)
    logo = FileBrowseField(
        _('company logo'), max_length=255, directory='company/', extensions=['.png']
    )
    address = models.TextField(_('company address'))
    phone = LTRCharField(_('company phone'), max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('company')
        verbose_name_plural = _('company')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

The migrate management command gives me this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'company.models.Company'; 'company.models' is not a package

When I look at the migration file I see this line has error:
import company.models.Company

I can't figure out what is the issue here?

from company.models import Company

I believe you must have forgotten to alert Python that the migration (folder) is a package, not just a folder by including __init__.py file in the migration folder. Without the init file above it can't work. This mostly occurs when we delete the migration folder and recreate it again without alerting Python that it is a package for any import, we want to carry out to take place. Also, ensure that company is part of your INSTALLED_APPS list in your settings.py file

#create this file inside your migration folder, and even check your company's app whether it has it, if not kindly create the file there also.
__init__.py

However, if the error persists which I doubt, then change the import path to:
from company.models import Company



This is a default Django installation. The migration folder is created automatically. Anyway it looks like the issue was the nested classes.
